# parallel programming mode: Scala vs OpenCL

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, opencl

In term of the parallel programing model, what is the difference between what Scala and OpenCL provided/supported?

Taking a trivial task for example, how to parallel a task of add for two vector with 1 billion elements?

I assume Scale should be much easy ,from a programer's point of view.

`vectorA+ vectorB -> setC`

Or, they are not at same level for comparison?

Comment: Scala is a high level and general purpose programming language - it is easy to work with and easy to parallelise using the CPU. OpenCL operates at a much lower level and is therefore much more difficult to work with. However, OpenCL allows you to parallelise using both your CPU and your GPU - for some tasks, using the GPU could be orders of magnitudes faster in terms of processing speed.

Comment: The're is a project that invalidates this question) https://github.com/ochafik/ScalaCL

Comment: @vitalli beats me .. however, it does not work yet:)

Comment: @SimonTodd  Scala parallel only on CPU? good point made!

Answer (score 0):

come across a very interesting article

http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2257035/amd-thinks-most-programmers-will-not-use-cuda-or-opencl

> While AMD has worked hard to drive OpenCL, as Nvidia has with CUDA,
>   both companies are now looking at delivering the performance
>   advantages of using those two languages and incorporating them into
>   languages such as Java, Python and R.

Maybe they need to look into Scala as well :)

Answer (score 0):

scala is based on JVM. That means any Java optimized GPU stuff can be easily ported to Scala..
If the JVM will optimize bytecode on the fly then automatically Scala will also support it.
GPU programming is the future - unless we start seeing hundreds of i7 cores etc..
The issue wit CPU is that is very complex therefore higher watt consumption per core - heat issues etc..
However GPU can offload taks from CPU same way as the math coprocesor wasoffloading tasks early days.

A desktop CPU + GPU die would be interesting though.. moving the CPU inside the GPU card :-)..